# Chakra UI full height component

Tags: css, reactjs, chakra-ui

How to set my App component to full height? I even tried to set body tag to height 100% in my index.html but it didn't work out

Comment: Add some `html` `css` code you tried and facing problem in it

Comment: Well `%` value in `height`(or `width`) are relative to container . So making `height: 100vh` might work in your case

Comment: @Rana I want it to be relative

Comment: Yes with `100vh` height will be relative to viewport height

Comment: @Rana it's not the solution

Answer (score 11):

Just use css calc in your component:
`<Box h='calc(100vh)' />`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In React.js you don't *usually* tinker around with the `body` tags (*unless you know what you're doing*). The standard practice is to create a [`Container`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/container/usage) Chakra component & apply respective [Style Props](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/style-props) to it.

On that note, here's what you can do instead:

```
// in your App.js

import { ChakraProvider, Container } from "@chakra-ui/react"

function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Container minHeight="100vh">
        { /* ... contents of the container */ }
      </Container>
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
}
```

Notice the [`minHeight` style prop](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/style-props#layout-width-and-height) passed to the `Container` component. Chakra-UI will then style the container as if you're styling the "*container*" using the the [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) CSS property.

You can style that specific "*container*" with as many style props as Chakra-UI! And I recommend going through the documentations (see shared URL above) to figure what other style props are supported.

P.S: You can use a [`Box`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/box/usage) component too! But I prefer (and suggest) using the `Container` component instead because of its responsiveness & the ease of constraining it's child elements.

Comment: This approach works well if you use `minHeight="100vh"`, rather than `maxHeight`  - Upvoting assuming this adaption 

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I've edited the answer as per your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I had today the same problem, the height wouldn't extend as I wanted it. I'm using redwood.js together with Chakra-ui. My solution to extend the height was adding the style prop. I hope it helps someone

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="redwood-app" style='height:100vh'>
      <!-- Please keep the line below for prerender support. -->
      <%= prerenderPlaceholder %>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which is useful in conjunction with sticky footer style layouts, is to set global styles on the `#root` element (or whichever is your react mount element).

Here is an example producing a full height App component using flexbox, adapted from https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/#aa-there-is-flexbox:

```
// index.jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react"

// Call `extendTheme` and pass your custom values
const theme = extendTheme({
  styles: {
    global: {
      "#root": {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        minHeight: "100vh",
      },
    },
  },
  // ...other theme customisations
})

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement,
);
root.render(
  // Pass the new theme to `ChakraProvider`
  <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
    <App />
  </ChakraProvider>
);
```

```
// App.jsx
import { chakra } from '@chakra-ui/react';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <chakra.section sx={{ flex: '1 0 auto' }}>Content</chakra.section>
      <chakra.footer sx={{ flexShrink: '0' }}>Footer content</chakra.footer>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```